# How can I get around the "too many SOQL queries" error in my flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, opportunity-lineitem, scheduled-flow, opportunitylineitemschedule

All,

Not new to flow at all but can't figure out a workaround for this.

I have what I believe to be a simple flow. It queries the `OpportunityLineItem` object to see if a record has any `OpportunityLineItemSchedules` records associated with it.

This is what I'm wanting the flow to do

- Get `OpportunityLineItem` records with `OpportunityLineItemSchedules`
- If there's a related `OpportunityLineItemSchedules` record, then grab the MAX Schedule date record (SOQL syntax `SELECT Revenue From OpportunityLineItemSchedule ORDER BY ScheduleDate DESC LIMIT 1`) and store the `Revenue` and `OpportunityLineItemId` values into variables
- Loop through all of the `OpportunityLineItem` records and assign the `Last Period Revenue` value from the `Revenue` variable we stored in the previous step
- Lastly, update all `OpportunityLineItem` records in the collection with the variables specified

[image]

I'm hitting a `Too Many SOQL Queries 101` error. From what I gathered, it isn't best practice to have a get records element inside of a loop. What I'm trying to wrap my head around is how to overcome this. When I put the `OpportunityLineItemSchedules` **Get Records** element outside the loop, it only grabs one record. When it's inside the loop, it grabs each record I expect it to, but errors out.

I've read I could implement a **Pause** element **OR** create another loop to get the `OpportunityLineItemSchedules`. I'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement either of those solutions.

Wondering if I could get some guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem without using Apex would be to create another automation on the *OpportunityLineItemSchedule* object that, when that record is created or updated, it would update a date field on the parent opportunity line item. With this separate automation you remove the need to query for the schedule record within your loop, because you'll have this information on the item itself.

To work with this, besides creating this automation, you would have to update the existing line items too.